# In C get hard drive free space from device name

Tags: c, linux, hard-drive

In order to have stats on a hardrive one can use the [sys/statvfs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs)

It takes either a path or a fd.

```
int statvfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *buf);
int fstatvfs(int fd, struct statvfs *buf);
```

In my application I am parsing /proc/diskstats which provide me with the device name (ex: sda1, sda2).

I don't know how to use that device name in order to get the same stats as the statvfs functions.
What functions can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Read `/etc/mtab` and map device names to mount paths.

Answer (score 0):

To connect a device with where its mounted, look at `mount`.  The source for `mount` should tell you how to find the path each device is mounted on.  Then you can open the path and call `statvfs`